# ASP Left function issue

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have this code and something odd happening when I'm running it.

I have field number like 101512 up to 101520. I've used LEFT function to get rid of last two digits and keep the 1015. When i runn loop function for the first one it gives me 1015 but for the rest it gives me 101 an it elminates the last digit like this:

```
d = Split(Request("field"),",")  
For i = 1 To UBound(d)  
  Responce.Write(Left(d(i),4))  
Next
```

**Results**

```
1015  
101  
101  
101  
...
```

Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that `Request("field")` may be returning a string like the following:

```
101520, 101521, 101522
```

Note the space after each comma.  Thus when you apply `Left()` and print the value to your HTML output you don't notice the space but you only see three digits as the space counted as the first digit

One thing to try to see if this is the case is to change the code to the following:

```
Left(Trim(d(i)), 4)
```

That way any spaces around the value are removed before `Left()` is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to iterate over "multi value" request item is actually:

```
For i = 0 To Request("field").Count-1
   Response.Write(Request("field").Item(i) & "<br />")
Next
```

This will iterate the actual values without using `split` at all..